# ios objective-c const CGFloat *

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, nsarray, cgfloat

when I am calling

```
setLineDash:(nullable const CGFloat *) count:(NSInteger) phase:(CGFloat)
```

method by passing @[@1.0,@2.0] as (nullable const CGFloat *)

```
UIBezierPath *path = [self drawLine:start ended:ended];
[path setLineDash:@[@1.0, @2.0] count:2 phase:0.0];
```

I am keep getting this error;

```
Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const CGFloat * _Nullable' (aka 'const double *') is disallowed with ARC
```

any suggestion? what's the right argument to pass in here.

appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CGFloat dash_pattern[]={1.0,2.0};
[path setLineDash:dash_pattern count:2 phase:0.0];
```

Comment: it works. tks a lot. so does (const X *) always mean passing a c style pointer. what does const means.